# Where does bmgr store the backups when using LocalTransport?

Tags: backup, backup-manager

I've successfully triggered a backup using `bmgr`:

```
$ adb shell bmgr list transports
  * com.android.localtransport/.LocalTransport

$ adb shell bmgr transport com.android.localtransport/.LocalTransport
Selected transport com.android.localtransport/.LocalTransport (formerly com.android.localtransport/.LocalTransport)

$ adb shell bmgr enable true
Backup Manager now enabled

$ adb shell bmgr backupnow com.mirfatif.mylocation
Running incremental backup for 1 requested packages.
Package @pm@ with result: Success
Package com.mirfatif.mylocation with progress: 2560/3072
Package com.mirfatif.mylocation with progress: 3072/3072
Package com.mirfatif.mylocation with progress: 5632/3072
Package com.mirfatif.mylocation with result: Success
Backup finished with result: Success
```

Now **where can I find this backup archive** (presumably `*.ab`) on the device? Is it in a location accessible without root powers?

<sup>(if you wonder for the background: with `adb backup` being deprecated, and Android 12 said to only backup data for apps marked as debug, I'm looking for an alternative allowing me to have my backups in a location of **my** choosing. On that path I'm exploring `bmgr`, but this piece of information seems missing and did not surface during my searching the web. If it's possible for an end-user to define a dedicated transport with a storage end-point of choice, hints on that are welcome too and considered valid answers as long as they meet the goal)</sup>

Comment: `/data/data/com.android.localtransport/files/1/_delta/`

Comment: Ah, I was afraid of something like that. Thanks, @IrfanLatif – so there's no way to get to those files without root I guess (to copy them off-device and e.g. copy back and restore after a factory reset)?

Comment: Correct. AFAIK.

Comment: Hope we're both proven wrong then by someone (there's still a chance if there's an easy way to establish your own transport) – but afraid you're right. It's safe if Google gets our backups, but dangerous if we do, even when encrypted… Thanks once more!

Comment: Backup transports need signature level permission: `android.permission.BACKUP`. Else [Seedvault](https://github.com/seedvault-app/seedvault) could have been installed as a normal app.